# Shortest match issues

Tags: regex, perl

I know the ? operator enables "non greedy" mode, but I am running into a problem, I can't seem to get around. Consider a string like this:

```
my $str = '<a>sdkhfdfojABCasjklhd</a><a>klashsdjDEFasl;jjf</a><a>askldhsfGHIasfklhss</a>';
```

where there are opening and closing tags `<a>` and `</a>`, there are keys ABC, DEF and GHI but are surrounded by some other random text. I want to replace the `<a>klashsdjDEFasl;jjf</a>` with `<b>TEST</b>` for example. However, if I have something like this:

```
$str =~ s/<a>.*?DEF.*?<\/a>/<b>TEST><\/b>/;
```

Even with the non greedy operators .*?, this does not do what I want. I know why it does not do it, because the first `<a>` matches the first occurrence in the string, and matches all the way up to DEF, then matches to the nearest closing `</a>`. What I want however is a way to match the closest opening `<a>` and closing `</a>` to "DEF" though. So currently, I get this as the result:

```
<a>TEST</b><a>askldhsfGHIasfklhss</a>
```

Where as I am looking for something to get this result:

```
<a>sdkhfdfojABCasjklhd</a><b>TEST</b><a>askldhsfGHIasfklhss</a>
```

By the way, I am not trying to parse HTML here, I know there are modules to do this, I am simply asking how this could be done.

Thanks,
Eric Seifert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str =~ s/(.*)<a>.*?DEF.*?<\/a>/$1<b>TEST><\/b>/;
```

The problem is that even with non-greedy matching, Perl is still trying to find the match that starts at the leftmost possible point in the string.  Since `.*?` can match `<a>` or `</a>`, that means it will always find the first `<a>` on the line.

Adding a greedy `(.*)` at the beginning causes it to find the *last* possible matching `<a>` on the line (because `.*` first grabs the whole line, and then backtracks until a match is found).

One caveat:  Because it finds the rightmost match first, you can't use this technique with the `/g` modifier.  Any additional matches would be inside `$1`, and `/g` resumes the search where the previous match ended, so it won't find them.  Instead, you'd have to use a loop like:

```
1 while $str =~ s/(.*)<a>.*?DEF.*?<\/a>/$1<b>TEST><\/b>/;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a dot which says: *"match any character"*, use what you really need which says: *"match any char that is not the start of `</a>`"*. This translates into something like this:

```
$str =~ s/<a>(?:(?!<\/a>).)*DEF(?:(?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>/<b>TEST><\/b>/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = '<a>sdkhfdfojABCasjklhd</a><a>klashsdjDEFasl;jjf</a><a>askldhsfGHIasfklhss</a>';

my @collections = $str =~ /<a>.*?(ABC|DEF|GHI).*?<\/a>/g;

print join ", ", @collections;
```

Comment: All you did was change the regex so it matches every occurrence of `<a>...</a>` in the string.  That doesn't solve the original problem, which is to match only one of those groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
s{
   <a>
   (?: (?! </a> ) . )*
   DEF   
   (?: (?! </a> ) . )*
   </a>
}{<b>TEST</b>}x;
```

Basically,

```
(?: (?! PAT ) . )
```

is the equivalent of

```
[^CHARS]
```

for regex patterns instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, this is what you are looking for.

Use of Lazy quantifiers `?` with no global flag is the answer.

Eg,

[image]

If you had global flag `/g` then, it would have matched all the lowest length matches as below. 
[image]