# Perl: extract substring that match a pattern between to XML tag

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I need to parse an XML file without using module.

In that XML file I need to extract all content between 2 tags (`<mi>`...`</mi>`) that match a pattern.

I have this:

```
$xmlstring = my xml string
$pattern = "G2_CPU";
my $regex = "<mi>(.*?" . $pattern . ".*?)<\\/mi>";
my ($data) = $xmlstring =~ /$regex/i;
```

But when I execute it, in `$data` I got everything between the very first `<mi>` tag and the very last `</mi>` tag.

I also try with the regex without variable: `/(<mi>.*?G2_CPU.*?<\/mi>)/` and I got the same result.

How can I do it?

Comment: You have `$compteur` in the regex and you talk about `$pattern`. Are you sure you have the proper variable naming?

Comment: Sorry, wrong cut/paste, please replace `$pattern = "G2_CPU"` by `$compteur = "G2_CPU"`

Comment: XML is not a regex parsable structure. It's very hazardous to go down this road, because it'll create brittle code that'll mysteriously break one day.

Comment: @Maximilien: What are your reasons for avoiding a proper XML parser? You really can't do this reliably using regular expressions.

Comment: This script will be run on an telecom equipment on which I cannot install perl module

Comment: If you can put your script on said equipment, you can also put at least any non-XS module on said equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a greedy match in the beginning of the pattern, so that it catches the most of it:

```
my $regex = "(?:.*)<mi>(.*?" . $compteur . ".*?)<\/mi>";
             ^^^^^^
```

From [Shortest match issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757967/1983854):

> The problem is that even with non-greedy matching, Perl is still
>   trying to find the match that starts at the leftmost possible point in
>   the string.

#### Test

File `p.pl`:

```
$xmlstring = "hello <mi>first mi</mi> and this is another <mi>second mi</mi> end." ;
$compteur="second";
my $regex = "(?:.*)<mi>(.*?" . $compteur . ".*?)<\/mi>";
my ($data) = $xmlstring =~ /$regex/i;
print "$data\n";
```

Execution:

```
$ perl p.pl 
second mi
```

Comment: This will match `<mi>aaa</mi> <tag>second</tag> <mi>bbb</mi>` i.e. it will find the pattern between *any* two opening and closing `mi` tags, not necessarily two that pair with one another.

Comment: @Borodin Uhms, I see, hadn't thought about it. Do you see any way to improve it? I am not that familiar with Perl regex.

Comment: @fedorqui: I'm afraid I'm in the camp that says you shouldn't be trying to do this with regexes anyway! You could use something like `(?:.(?!</mi>))` to match any character that isn't followed by `</mi>`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is still valid XML, i.e. `<` cannot appear between tag open and tag close, ***and*** there is no `CDATA` within those tags, you can just use:

```
my $re = qr{<mi>([^<]*? \Q$pattern\E [^<]*?)</mi>}ix;
```

That is, instead of allowing *any* character up to the substring of interest, allow just non-tag opening characters.

Also, my first instinct, if I ever thought I would try to [go down the rabbit hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) of parsing XML without a decent XML parser, would have been to first extract the text between `<mi>...</mi>` and then check if it contains what I am looking for.

Comment: I cannot use you solution, cause I have other tags inside `<mi>`and `</mi>`